# Able to run incomplete query in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

*Oracle 18c; SQL Developer 18.1.0.095 Build 095.1630:*

Using this sample data:

```
create table assets (asset_id varchar2(10));
  
begin
  insert into assets (asset_id) values ('01');
  insert into assets (asset_id) values ('02');
  insert into assets (asset_id) values ('02');
end;
/
commit;
```

In SQL Developer, I can run a query that only is a partial WHERE clause expression; it doesn't have a SELECT or FROM clause.

I select the following query using my mouse and hit `CTRL+Enter`:

```
asset_id) in 
    (
    select
        asset_id
    from
        assets
    where
        asset_id = '02'
     )
```

Result:

[image]

---

Why did that query run successfully, despite it missing a SELECT and FROM clause?

Comment: Did you perhaps have the text of the inner query highlighted at the time?

Comment: @AlexPoole I had the whole query selected when I hit CTRL+Enter. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that's because cursor was somewhere (anywhere) within the parenthesis, i.e. on a valid SQL statement which was then executed and returned result.

If you, on the other hand, move cursor to the 1st line (`asset_id) in`) you'll get an error saying

> Error starting at line : 11 in command - asset_id) in Error report -
> Unknown Command
>
> SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter
> EXIT.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect SQL Developer is ignoring the first line, and simply running the subquery.

I imagine it is doing what F5 would do, but behind the scenes.

F5:

```
Error starting at line : 13 in command -
asset_id) in
Error report -
Unknown Command


ASSET_ID  
----------
02
02
```

Whereas, when I hit CTRL+Enter, I think it's hiding the error from the first line, and only showing the result of the subquery (as if it were a standalone query).

Answer (score 0):

Changing your query so we can all play along.

```
asset_id) in 
    (
    select
        1
    from
        dual
    where
        1=1
     )
```

Placing my cursor in the select portion of the query, and hitting ctrl+Enter

We see the lines 2 through 9 light up, and then we get a response of 1.

What does SQL Developer actually run? See the Log panel, specifiaclly the Statements page. That logs every single thing we execute across the JDBC driver.

The parser based on the curpos makes a best guess as to what you're trying to run, and executes that.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQL Developer.*